# Vectorizing this operation with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, performance, math, vectorization

To introduce this problem, let's say that I have a 2D array (Nx3) storing N points. On the other hand, I have a 1D array (M, 3) containing the coordinates of a single 3D reference point therefore M=1

For this case, if I wanted to compute a new 1D array (N) with all the distances to the reference point, I would only need to do:

```py
import numpy as np

N = 100
M = 1
points = np.random.random((N, 3))
references = np.random.random((M, 3))

print(np.linalg.norm(points - references, axis=1))
```

And this works. However, when I have more than 1 reference point (`M>1`), numpy is not able to broadcast the operation. Right now I am just doing same operation as described before but with a for loop to iterate one by one over the reference points, which is quite inefficient.

How can I implement the above behaviour in a vectorized manner when having `M > 1`? Things I considered before:

- Using `numba.njit` to remove the effect of the python interpreted `for`. But I would like to do it without `numba`
- Something like broadcasting the points-array to 3D (MxNx3) and the reference-array to 3D (NxMx3) so that I can operate them. However, if I am not wrong, I would be multiplying by M the size of the points array and by N the size of the reference array. In case this is the solution, I am not sure how to do it either.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```py
np.linalg.norm(references - points[:, None], axis=-1)
```

Which gives you a `M,N` array of all distances.

Example:

```py
np.random.seed(0)  # reproducible setup
N = 4
M = 2
points = np.random.random((N, 3))
references = np.random.random((M, 3))

>>> np.linalg.norm(references - points[:, None], axis=-1)
array([[0.57216693, 0.86543108],
       [0.76350759, 0.63809564],
       [0.90274337, 0.94847268],
       [0.51150232, 0.88049546]])
```

Note: if you are dealing with a large number of points, and not necessarily interested in the full list of distances, but a subset of, say, nearest neighbors, then you should look into use [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html). This will be much faster and memory efficient.

Comment: You can also mention the scipy [KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree) implementation.

Comment: oops, that's what I meant to link to... Amended. Thx, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Do the broadcasting when you take the difference of the arrays and then apply `np.linalg.norm` to the last axis (I explicitly wrote 2, but you could also use -1).

```py
np.linalg.norm(points[:,None] - references[None,:], axis=2)
```

Just note that you will end up with a column vector when M = 1 when your version gives you a 1D vector. If you want a row vector, then swap the `points` and `references` indices. This will also have the effect of transposing the final result. I'm not sure which orientation you prefer.